# BASH: How do I select all of the characters in a string after a given character?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

I'm writing a script to check MIPS syntax. Take the following as an example:

```
lw $t11 9($t2)
```

In bash, how can I select all of the characters after the `t`, in this case `11`, in `$t11`

**EDIT:** Just FYI, I'll be selecting any characters founder after "$t" or "$s" and checking that the integers are within a specified range.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BASH regex:

```
s='lw $t11 9($t2)'
[[ "$s" =~ t([^ ]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
11
```